# Retrieving an array of objects from Firestore with the admin sdk and Firebase cloud functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I am working on a Next JS app with Firebase and I am stuck on Firebase Cloud functions and how to retrieve data after an onCreate or onUpdate trigger. I am new to the admin SDK so pardon me if the question looks simple.

My document structure looks like this:

```
{
  "amount" : 123, 
  "code" : "RAB45MGTRK",
  "createdOn" : "Wed Jan 11 2023 08:34:25 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)",
  "phone" : "0700 000 000", 
  "rice" : "160",
  "sugar" : "136",
  "user_id" : "IjsdigsdTr345499",
  "items" : [
    {
      "product" : "productOne", 
      "quantity" : "2"
    },
        {
      "product" : "productTwo", 
      "quantity" : "3"
    }
  ]
}
```

I retrieve the data like this:

```
    exports.productPurchased = functions.firestore
    .document('purchases/{productPurchaseId}')
    .onCreate((doc, context) => {
      const documentId = context.params.productPurchaseId;
      const purchaseData = doc.data();

       const purchase = {
        amount: `${purchaseData.amount}`,
        uid: `${purchaseData.user_id}`,
        phoneNumber: `${purchaseData.phone}`, 
        items: `${purchaseData.items}`, //this is where I have the issue
        docId: documentId,
        createdOn: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
    }

    return productPurchase(purchase)
  })
```

The other fields are retrieved Ok, the challenge is with the array. I would like to get the array of objects and and insert them into the purchase object such that they become:

```
"productOne" : "2", 
"productTwo" : "3"
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the backticks to get the array

```
    exports.productPurchased = functions.firestore
    .document('purchases/{productPurchaseId}')
    .onCreate((doc, context) => {
      const documentId = context.params.productPurchaseId;
      const purchaseData = doc.data();

       const purchase = {
        amount: `${purchaseData.amount}`,
        uid: `${purchaseData.user_id}`,
        phoneNumber: `${purchaseData.phone}`, 
        items: purchaseData.items, //this is where I have the issue
        docId: documentId,
        createdOn: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
    }

    return productPurchase(purchase)
  })
```

and in your productPurchase function, receive the object:

```
const productPurchase = (data => {
    const newData = data;
    const pArray = Object.entries(data.items);

    pArray.forEach(([key, val]) => {
        newData[val.product] = val.quantity;
    })

    //do what you want with newData
})
```